# Andriod Studio, Buttons and lists

Tags: android-studio

So, I am trying to create a code in android studio that allows the user to add a name to a list using a button. So when the user clicks the button a keyboard shows and he types the name and the name shows in a tiny list down the screen. I am a beginner in coding, but I've tried every website and I didn't find anything. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple example of adding names to the listview, you can refer to:

[![activity_main.xml][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRZub.png

[![Mainctivity.java][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2OoJ.png